# Access 2013, Module Not Generating Fields on Word 2013 Document, but Function Within Main Form Does

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a simple Access 2013 database that currently has one table, and one form for inputting data.  I input data using the form, things like first name, last name, etc.  I then have the database calling a function that takes these values, and places them on a word document in specific areas, (similar to mail merge, but mail merge doesn't suit my exact needs.) The function then converts a copy of that word document to a .pdf, and saves it in a location that is pre-defined.

I currently have the function tied to a button that is on the form.  Everything works fine now, and I would like to break the soon-to-be large amount of code that will follow into modules; however, this is where I am having the issue.  When I place this function in a module, it does not populate all of the form fields on the word document.  It only populates one or two fields, not all of them.  If I place the code back in a function that is on the main form, it works just fine.

I do not get any errors either way.  The .pdf is created and stored exactly where it is supposed to be, but if the button calls the module, it doesn't populate all of the fields.  If the button calls the function within the same form, it works like a champ.  I will post a shortened version of the code below.

My initial thoughts are that perhaps I am not calling the module correctly, but at this point, I am lost.  I have tried passing the values as 'Function Memo(LN, FN, srcFile) As String', labeling individually 'As String', but I can't seem to get it to work.

```
Function Memo(LN, FN, srcFile)
Dim appword As Object
Dim doc As Object
Dim Path As String
Dim pdfFileName As String
Dim folderName As String
Dim directory As String

Path = srcFile
folderName = LN & ", " & FN
directory = Application.CurrentProject.Path & "\" & folderName
pdfFileName = directory & "\" & folderName & " 2015 Memo" & ".pdf"

If Dir(directory, vbDirectory) = "" Then
    MkDir (directory)

Else

End If

On Error Resume Next
Error.Clear

Set appword = GetObject(, "word.application")
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
Set appword = CreateObject("Word.Application")
appword.Visible = False
End If

Set doc = appword.Documents.Open(Path, , True)

With doc
.FormFields("TextFN1").Result = FN
.FormFields("TextMI1").Result = MI
.FormFields("TextLN11").Result = LN

.ExportAsFixedFormat pdfFileName, 17

 appword.Visible = False
 Set doc = appword.Documents.Close()

 appword.Quit SaveChanges:=False

 End With

 Set doc = Nothing
 Set appword = Nothing
 End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Wow. Silly me.  After some additional exploratory surgery on the code, I found my problem.  The issue is that a few of my variables did not have unique names.  Problem solved.